# Firefox not starting after upgrading to 8.0.1 on Debian Lenny box

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, upgrade

I upgraded to Firefox 8.0.1 on my Debian Lenny box and now Firefox won't start at all.

I downloaded the installer in `/var/username/Desktop`, extracted it to `/usr/local` and created a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/firefox`.

After that, if I type Firefox from the home directory it gives me the following message:

> -bash: /usr/bin/firefox: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried this sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox /usr/bin/firefox and still i get the same message

Comment: i mean i created a symbolic link by this command - sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox /usr/bin/firefox and then if i type firefox i get the message stating no such file or directory

Comment: sorry about that i was logged in as super user. I updated the message i am getting back. Still the same message

Comment: Its finally working. My problem was i was using 32 bit version of ff. I installed the 64 one and it works fine now. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer and accept it? You'll get some reputation for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i was using 32 bit version of ff. I installed the 64 one and it works fine now. Thanks all for your help.